# Can I travel to other destinations on multi-entry visa on separate trips?

Tags: schengen-visas, multiple-entry

I am a non-UK resident working in the UK, since it was my first time, I had applied for a single entry visa for 3 days to Netherlands.
After completing the visa process, the consulate ended up giving me a multi-entry 1 year visa even though I asked for a single entry one.

So can I use this visa to not go to Netherlands for any of my future trips and just visit other schengen countries say, Germany adhering to the 90/180 days rule?
Do I need to make conscious effort to keep my number of days in Netherlands always more than any of the other schengen countries?

I particularly ask this because of some rules viz. primary destination of trip needs to be the issuing country, border force in some countries (Finland?) make note of your itinerary on exit and if issuing country is not on the list they flag your details. I don't want to hurt my chances of getting visa in future applications if it *violates* any of the rules.